# JS merge array and divide merged values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 2 arrays which have a unique key `name`

```
const a1 = [  
   {  
      "name":"foo",
      "count":5,
   },
   {  
      "name":"bar",
      "count":0,
   }
]
const a2 = [  
   {  
      "name":"foo",
      "pop":58,
   },
   {  
      "name":"bar",
      "pop":22,
   }
]
```

I then need to create `a3` which has the properties of `a1` and `a2` as well as a third property `result` which is equal to `pop/count`

I have got working being able to merge the 2 arrays here:

```
  const a3 = [a1, a2].reduce((a, b) =>
    a.map((c, i) => Object.assign({}, c, b[i]))
  );
```

My expected result is

```
a3 = [  
   {  
      "name":"foo",
      "count":5,
      "pop":58,
      "result": 11.6
   },
   {  
      "name":"bar",
      "count":0,
      "pop":22,
      "result": infinity
   }
]
```

However I am stuck trying to add in the new property in this reduce function. I have looked over many similar questions but can't find a question which helps me out in this situation.

Comment: `22/0` is `Infinity`, not `0`

Comment: Will they be in the same order in both the arrays?

Comment: Yes @adiga the order is the same in both arrays. Hence my message about the current merge working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for `reduce` here, just `map`. Since the order is the same, it's fairly simple to just map through one of them and grab the object from the other, then do your combination and calculation:

```js
const a1 = [  
   {  
      "name":"foo",
      "count":5,
   },
   {  
      "name":"bar",
      "count":0,
   }
];
const a2 = [  
   {  
      "name":"foo",
      "pop":58,
   },
   {  
      "name":"bar",
      "pop":22,
   }
];

const result = a1.map((obj1, index) => {
    const obj2 = a2[index];
    //assert: obj1.name === obj2.name
    return {
        name: obj1.name,
        count: obj1.count,
        pop: obj2.pop,
        result: obj2.pop / obj1.count
    };
});

console.log(result);
```

Or with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which is a bit cleaner but harder to follow until you're used to it:

```js
const a1 = [  
   {  
      "name":"foo",
      "count":5,
   },
   {  
      "name":"bar",
      "count":0,
   }
];
const a2 = [  
   {  
      "name":"foo",
      "pop":58,
   },
   {  
      "name":"bar",
      "pop":22,
   }
];

const result = a1.map(({name, count}, index) => {
    const {name: name2, pop} = a2[index];
    //assert: name === name2
    return {
        name,
        count,
        pop,
        result: pop / count
    };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If elements are not in the same order.

```js
const a1 = [  
 {  
   "name":"foo",
   "count":5,
 },
 {  
   "name":"bar",
   "count":0,
 }
]
const a2 = [  
 {  
   "name":"foo",
   "pop":58,
 },
 {  
   "name":"bar",
   "pop":22,
 }
]

let out = a1.map(e => {
 let {pop} = a2.find(({name}) => name = e.name);
 return {...e, pop, result: isFinite(pop/e.count)? pop/e.count : 0}
});
console.log(out)
```

And if elements are in the same order

```js
const a1 = [  
 {  
   "name":"foo",
   "count":5,
 },
 {  
   "name":"bar",
   "count":0,
 }
]
const a2 = [  
 {  
   "name":"foo",
   "pop":58,
 },
 {  
   "name":"bar",
   "pop":22,
 }
]

let out = a1.map((e, i) => {
 let {pop} = a2[i];
 return {...e, pop, result: isFinite(pop/e.count)? pop/e.count : 0}
});
console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const a3 = [a1, a2].reduce((a, b) =>
       a.map((c, i) => Object.assign({result: b[i].pop/c.count}, c, b[i]))
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

Not great but working. Please add a 'do not divide by zero'

```
var res = a1.concat(a2).reduce( (acc, v) => {
   acc[v.name] = acc[v.name] || {};
   ['count', 'pop'].filter( k => v[k] !== undefined).forEach( k => acc[v.name][k] = acc[v.name][k] || v[k] );
   return acc;
}, {});

Object.keys(res).forEach( k => res[k].result = res[k].pop / res[k].count);
```